# Use value from dictionary as column header in Sqlite query

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, dictionary

I have an Sqlite database that I need to query from python.

The database only has two columns, "key" and "Value", and the value column contains a dictionary with multiple values. What I want to do is create a query to use some of those known dictionary keys as column headers, and the corresponding data under that column.

Is it possible to do that all in a query, or will I have to process the dictionary in python afterwards?

Example data (values obviously have been changed) that I want to query.

```
key                             |   Value
/auth/user_data/fb_me_user      | {"uid":"100008112345597","first_name":"Tim","last_name":"Robins","name":"Tim Robins","emails":["t.robins@gmail.com"]"}
```

There are lots of other key / value combinations, but this is one of the ones I am interested in.

I would like to query this to produce the following;

```
UID              |  Name        |   Email
100008112345597  |  Tim Robins  |   t.robins@gmail.com
```

Is that possible just in a query?

Thanks

Comment: i would say as your getting result from facebook . you can prevent this before inserting the result to sqlite. parse result with json and insert as different columns.Since Prevention is better than cure

Comment: Im getting this from the facebook app though, and have no control over how the data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

after querying you get the value like below. from them you can get

```
value='''{"uid":"100008112345597","first_name":"Tim","last_name":"Robins","name":"Tim Robins","emails":["t.robins@gmail.com"]}'''

import ast
details=ast.literal_eval(value)
print details['uid'],details['name'],','.join(details['emails'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can process the values after the query, but really want to know if it possible to do the whole thing with just a query.

Comment: @James i think that is not possible.